# Difference between using mysql in xampp and using mysql separately

Tags: server, php, mysql, xampp

I have used xampp on windows to do some php programming(basic) and now i'm trying to do some python/perl database connectivity programs(again basic) with mysql. The thing is when i used xampp, it already had the sql but in my college lab we used mysql directly(they had installed it separately) without using xampp...... so i want to know what differences are there in using these 2 methods and which i should know to make sure that I'm learning programming properly
ps. if someone could also list syntax differences(if there are any) in db connectivity while using xampp and mysql direclty it would be even more helpful or telling me to refer a link would also be fine

Comment: mySQL i will be the same in both cases. XAMP is a bundled 'package' (like buying shampoo bundled with a soap bar and a sponge) since they are used together, while just installing mySQL is just the single program (just buying the shampoo) since you won't need the other stuff.